# expected value of harmonic mean

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with expected value $\mu$. Can we compute the expected value of the harmonic mean:
$$
\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_i}}
$$
thanks for helpers!

Comment: You need to know the distribution of $X_i$. In http://www.pnas.org/content/111/44/15681.full various versions of the problem are considered, and in particular for $X_i\sim U(0,1)$ they get that $E[H_n] = \frac{1}{\log n}\left(1+\frac{c}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not from that information alone.  For example, for $n=2$ we have
$$ \dfrac{2}{1/X_1 + 1/X_2} = \dfrac{2 X_1 X_2}{X_1 + X_2}$$
If $X_i = \mu$ with probability $1$, the expected value would be $\mu$; if
$X_i = \mu/2$ or $3\mu/2$, each with probability $1/2$, it would be $7\mu/16$.

EDIT: Let's assume your random variables are always positive (if not, you may have trouble even defining the expected value of the harmonic mean because of zero or near-zero values of the denominator).  The harmonic mean of $n$ positive numbers is always less than or equal to the arithmetic mean, and equal only in the case where all the numbers are equal.  So the only way the expected value of the harmonic mean can be $\mu$ is when the random variables are equal to $\mu$ with probability $1$.

Comment: thanks! are there some conditions so the expected value is always $\mu$? like the arithmetic mean

Comment: could you explain how do you infer that the expected value of the harmonic mean can be μ only when the random variables are equal to μ with probability 1? and is there any difference if the random variables are countinious?

Comment: Let $h(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be the harmonic mean of $x_1, \ldots, x_n \ge 0$ and $a(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1 + \ldots + x_n)/n$ their arithmetic mean.  Consider the random variable $Y = a(X_1, \ldots, X_n) - h(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.  We have $Y \ge 0$ a.s., with $Y > 0$ when $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are not all equal.  Therefore if $P(X_1 = \ldots = X_n) < 1$ we would have $E[Y] > 0$.