# With $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ what is the limit of $\frac{n}{x_1^{-1} + \cdots + x_n^{-1}}$

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, law-of-large-numbers

I am confused as to how I can tackle this question:

With $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ what is the limit of $\frac{n}{x_1^{-1} + \cdots + x_n^{-1}}$.

My assumption is that is $0$. but I would like to show that this limit almost surely converges to it. I started with characteristic functions:
$$\mathbb{E}exp({it\frac{n}{x_1^{-1} + \cdots + x_n^{-1}}})$$
I however do not see how to expand this.

Then I thought, well... take $X = \{X(\omega_1), X(\omega_2) , \cdots\}$ and $N = \{\#\{X(\omega_i) < 1\} < \infty , \#\{X(\omega_i) = x\} = \infty , \forall i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Where (I presume, but need to prove) that $\mathbb{P}(N) = 0$. So take any sequence in $N^c$ which has probability one of occuring, then I am not quite sure how to continue.

One main difficulty I find, is that $\mathbb{E}X_i^{-1} =\infty$ so I can't use the law of large numbers.

Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Maybe it is possible  to prove that the reciprocal of the quantity goes to infinity almost surely by the (modified) law of large numbers?

Comment: @Shashi do you mind elaborating? What is the modified law of large numbers?

Comment: I don't how people call it, but the theorem that says if for a sequence of iid random variable $Y_i$ one has $E(Y^+) =\infty$ and $E(Y^-) <\infty$ then the sample mean diverges to plus infinity a.s.

Comment: @Shashi What there is $Y^+$ and $Y^-$ ?

Comment: $Y^+$ is the positive part of the random variable, i.e. $Y^+=\max\{0,Y\}$. Similarly $Y^-=-\min\{0,Y\}$. I would suggest you look up the Law of large numbers for infinite mean. I cannot elaborate neatly since I'm on my phone.

Comment: A quick search found this [very relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061406), wherein a [free paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/44/15681.full)  that cites a classic textbook is very helpful.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin this does become easier to search once one knows its called harmonic mean! Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact relation between $X$ and $x_1,...,x_n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{X_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{X_n}}$ is the harmonic mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, hence by assuming that $X_k$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent we have that the PDF of $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{X_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{X_n}}$ is supported on $(0,1)$ as well.

$$\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{n}{\frac{1}{X_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{X_n}}\geq\frac{1}{M}\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{X_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{X_n}\right)\leq M\right] $$
and if $X_k$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ the PDF of $\frac{1}{X_k}$ is supported on $(1,+\infty)$ and given by $\frac{1}{x^2}$, hence the expected value of $\frac{1}{X_k}$ is unbounded. In particular for any $M\gg 1$ the limit of the RHS as $n\to +\infty$ is zero, hence the limit distribution is a Dirac $\delta$ as conjectured.

---

About a similar problem: if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ and independent, the PDF of their **geometric** mean is supported on $(0,1)$ and given$^{(*)}$ by $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!}\left(-a\log a\right)^n$.
 This is a unimodal distribution with constant mode $\frac{1}{e}$ and mean $\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}$.

$(*)$ This can be shown by computing the CDF through some change of variables, then differentiating it, or through the following approach. Let $g(x)$ be the PDF of $\text{GM}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. We have
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^h g(x)\,dx = \mathbb{E}[X_1^{h/n}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^{h/n}]=\frac{1}{(1+h/n)^n}, $$
hence
$$ \mathcal{L}(g(x))(s) = \sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^h s^h}{h!(1+h/n)^n} $$
and by inversion
$$ g(x)=\left(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^h s^h}{h!(1+h/n)^n}\right)(x).$$

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with Dirac $\delta$. Do you mind elaborating a bit on that last point?

Comment: @rannoudanames: in other terms, the PDF of $\text{HM}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ gets more and more concentrated near zero as $n$ increases. You may also exploit the fact that $\text{HM}\leq\text{GM}$: the distribution of the geometric mean is a bit simpler to study.

Answer (score 2):

I was talking about the following theorem which you can find in Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples (the chapter on law of large numbers).

> **Theorem.** Let $Y_1, Y_2,...$ be i.i.d. with $E(Y_i^+) =\infty$ and $E(Y_i^-) <\infty$. Let $S_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$, then $S_n/n\to \infty$ a.s.

Define $Y_i=1/X_i$ where $X_i\sim\text{Unif}(0,1) $ i.i.d. Verify that these $Y_i$'s satisfy the theorem above. Hence
$$\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{n}\to \infty \ \ \ \text{a.s.}$$
But you are interested in the reciprocal of that, we conclude that 
$$\frac{n} {Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}\to 0\ \ \ \text{a.s.}$$